# Intuition for the prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

(surprisingly, it appears that this question has not been asked before)

Let $\pi(n)$ denote the number of primes $\leq n$. The prime number theorem states that

$$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log n} \  \text{as}  \ n \to +\infty$$

After painstakingly reading through Erdos's elementary proof of this theorem, I think I understand the mechanics of it from a *formal* perspective. However, I still don't seem to understand *intuitively* why this theorem is true. I would like some intuitive insight as to why this theorem holds.

I understand that for a result as deep as this one, even the intuition is going to contain some nitty-gritty details.  It's probably not the sort of thing that you could explain to a child, for example. Nevertheless, I will ask this question regardless. There has to be some convincing argument for this theorem beyond the technical details of the proofs.

Comment: If you move the $n$ to the other side, you get a statement about the density of the primes in the naturals.

Comment: Fair enough. It's just that this seems to be the more common way of presenting it.

Comment: Related: [Probabilistic interpretation of prime number theorem](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36897/probabilistic-interpretation-of-prime-number-theorem)

Comment: Wasn't asked before but will be asked plenty of times after.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not a full explanation, but it is too long for a comment.

Consider the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Start with the first $n$ numbers. Remove (one less than) $\frac 12$ of them as multiples of $2$, Of the remainder, remove $\frac 13$ of them as multiples of $3$. Of the remainder, remove $\frac 15$ as multiples of $5$, etc. You should be left with about $$n\prod_{p\le n, \text{ prime}}1 - \frac 1p$$

values as primes below $n$. Now, when multiplied out

$$\prod_{p\le n, \text{ prime}}1 - \frac 1p = 1 - \sum_{k \in S_n} \frac 1k$$
Where $S_n$ is the set of all square-free integers $> 1$ whose prime factors are $\le n$.

It remains to estimate that $1 - \sum_{k \in S_n} \frac 1k\approx \frac 1{\log n}$.

**Edit:**

Since it was already chosen as the solution and Winther has kindly provided Merten's 3rd theorem which says just what was needed, I could just let this go. But Merten's theorem strikes me as hardly more intuitively obvious than the prime number theorem itself, so I've been thinking on heuristic concepts to explain it.

Now for $|x| < 1$, $\frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + ...$ Therefore
$$\frac 1{\prod\limits_{p\le n}1 - \frac 1p} = \prod\limits_{p\le n}\left(1 + \frac 1p + \frac 1{p^2} + ...\right)$$

Multiplying the right side out, we get $\sum_{k \in R_n} \frac 1k$, where $R_n$ is the set of all integers whose prime factors are all $\le n$. Of these, it should be expected (I'm being heuristic here, so I can get away with that weasel-wording) that the sum for $k > n$ will be significantly smaller than for $k \le n$. Thus it seems reasonable that 
$$\sum_{k \in R_n} \frac 1k \sim \sum_{k \in R_n, k\le n} \frac 1k = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k \sim \log n$$

Comment: :D you capture everything I think of in a nut-shell.  +1

Comment: By [Mertens' 3rd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems) the asymptotic behavior of $\prod_{p\leq n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)$ is $\sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log(n)} \approx \frac{0.56}{\log(n)}$.

Comment: @Winther:  Does it follow from your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144940/intuition-for-the-prime-number-theorem/2145167#comment4413162_2145167) that $\prod_{p \leq n}\bigg({\dfrac{p}{p-1}}\bigg)$ is $\sim \dfrac{\log(n)}{e^{-{\gamma}}} \approx \dfrac{\log(n)}{0.56}$?

Comment: @ARNIEBEBITA-DRIS - That is a finite product, and you've inverted each factor, so yes, that inverts the entire product, which in turn inverts the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @PaulSinclair!  =)

Comment: @PaulSinclair But according to the Mertens' 3rd theorem, the "smaller sum" isn't that small, i.e., it does not go asymptotically zero when compared to the product term. Apparently, it is not easy to extract that natural logarithm.

Comment: @Husker - Note that I was not trying to prove anything here, but only aiming to provide some intuition that would suggest the results were reasonable to expect. The actual proofs are of course far beyond the trivial reasoning I gave.