# The Meaning of R's non-Trivial Zeros

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

(I have read through the various similar questions on SE listed by the system but not found an answer that helps).

Is there an intuitive explanation for why the Riemann zeta Function (rather than hypothesis) contains interesting information about the distribution of primes in language comprehensible to a non-mathematician?

Related questions might be...

What does a non-trivial zero indicate in respect of the distribution of primes? What do we learn from a zero when we find one?

I'm not sure, but it might also be same question if I ask how the input to the zeta function is related the output, or how the input value relates to locations on the number line.

But I'm muddled, as you can tell, so the related questions may be a red-herring. It's mainly the first question that I'm trying to answer.

Many thanks for your patience. Imagine I'm twelve years old and not Gauss.

Comment: Imagine $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \le x} \log p$ as a different version of the prime counting function $\pi(x) = \sum_{p \le x} 1$. The main point is the explicit formula $\psi(x) = x- \sum_{\rho \text{ non trivial zeros}} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} +f(x)$ where $f(x) = \frac12\log 2\pi-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{-2k}}{-2k} $ is almost constant. So from the non trivial zeros we know $\psi(x)$, and from the RH we know that for any $\sigma > 1/2$ then $\frac{\psi(x)-x}{x^{\sigma}} \to 0$. Until now we only know the prime number theorem saying it is true for $\sigma \ge 1$.

Comment: @reus -= Thank for trying but I can't see how this answers the question. I did warn you that I'm not a mathematician but I expect you've forgotten long ago what this is like. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Because there are no other ways to answer your questions. You are supposed to look at each term $\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$ and see how its growth rate depends only on $\Re(\rho)$. If some zeros of $\zeta(s)$ have real part $\ge \sigma$ then $\psi(x)-x$ grows at least as fast as $x^\sigma$. If the RH is true then $\psi(x)-x$ grows just a little faster than $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Let me try to help out with the 'how this answers the question' part. We start with the accepted answer to your previous question. It says '$\pi(x) \approx \int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln(t)} dt$ and the zeroes of $\zeta$ tell you what this "\approx" means, i.e. how far the left hand side can stray from the right hand side, expressed in terms of $x$'. Now given that answer there are two separate followup questions we could ask: 1) HOW exactly appear the zeroes in the description of how far the left and right hand side can differ? Do I add them? Multiply them? Subtract them? (ct in next comment)

Comment: ...and 2) WHY would the zeroes of $\zeta$ tell me anything about that? I don't see primes when I look at $\zeta$, so the relation to the left hand side is unclear, and frankly I don't see any logarithms either, so the relation to the right hand side isn't clear either.

The first thing you should understand is that reuns comment is a (and I think the best) answer to the FIRST of these two questions. If you are more interested in the second we have to wait for other answerers to  come by. But if you are interested in the first (as well) then I can help you a bit more with understanding reun.

Comment: I take it that you understand why people are happy with the formula '$\pi(x) \approx \int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln(t)} dt$: the left hand side clearly talks about the distribution of primes and the right hand side is something we can easily compute. The key to understand reuns comment is that anybody who is happy with '$\pi(x) \approx \int_2^x \frac{1}{\ln(t)} dt.$' would be equally happy with '$\psi(x) \approx x$'. 

I mean: clearly the right hand side is something we can compute and the left hand side tells you something about the distribution of primes. That is what we wanted, right? (ctd below)

Comment: You should stare a bit at the definition of $\psi$ to decide if it is 'better', 'worse' or 'exactly as good as' $\pi(x)$ in giving precise mathematical meaning to the semi-vague notion of 'the distribution of primes'. (Or you could read the Wikipedia page on the Prime Number Theorem that gives a solid argument that they are indeed, in a very precise sense,  equally good. If we accept for now that any formula with $\psi(x)$ on the left hand side and something actually computable on the right hand side makes us as happy as the accepted answer to your previous question, then we can see why...

Comment: ...reuns comment above is the best answer to question 1) above. Namely: the formula $\psi(x) \approx x$ is already good, but better would be to replace the $\approx$ with an actual $=$, at the cost of introducing an 'error term'. We know that we can do that, i.e. that there is *some* function $g(x)$ such that $\psi(x) = x + g(x)$. (This means that $g(x)$ describes the 'error' in the approximation $\psi(x) \approx x$.) Now the really great thing is that this $g(x)$ is made up of the zeroes of $\zeta$ (as described by reuns) plus something that is basically constant. This means that...

Comment: ...reuns (or rather Riemann's) formula tells you exactly what is the relationship between "zeroes of $\zeta$" on one hand and "the error/deviation in a very pretty formula for the distribution of primes" on the other. Hence we have a full answer to question 1. As said above question 2 is a different matter.

Comment: @Vincent - I very much appreciate your efforts. I'm still struggling though. I suspect I'm wasting everybody's time asking questions for which the answers will always be over my head. I'll ponder some more and study these answers.

Comment: Nah... just keep asking questions. I like them. And as you and  another commenter said below another post: the quest for the right question is often the most interesting part of learning math.

Comment: One thing you could ponder is: suppose we lived in a more perfect universe where the formula $\psi(x) = x$ were actually true for all (large enough) $x$ with no error terms involved. What would that mean? I.e. how would you use that (hypothetical) fact to get info about more down to earth questions about primes you might ask.

Comment: @Vincent - Thanks. What about if I asked this - If someone were to prove that the primes behave according to a fixed rule that ensures the PNT (or some rule) is always correct with just a small and computable error term - would this allow us decide RH? Or, must RH be proved independently of the actual behaviour of the primes? Again, the question is about the closeness of the relationship between Zeta and the primes.

Comment: This seems like a OK question for this site. Notice that the 'or' does not mean that the two questions are two mutually exclusive alternatives for the same thing; you are really asking two mostly independent questions here! The short answers are 'depends on how small is "small"' for the first and 'no' for the second - if you make the questions a separate post I or someone else will give you the long answers. You can do that now, or perhaps think  a bit about if you could have predicted these very short answers and tweak your questions a bit as a result - I leave that up to you.

Comment: O wait... I read 'error term' as something of the form "smaller than this-and-this number". But in my own earlier comment I introduced the phrase error term as something of the form "exactly this-and-this number". If the hypothetical result from your question would have that form (i.e. an *exactly* computable error term) you would have the holy grail of mathematics and the short answer to the first quesiton would be "yes". Of course a longer answer would still be more interesting.

Comment: @Vincent - I'm able to follow all of this and it's very helpful. I need to do some thinking before saying any more. I think I'm slowly approaching the question I should have asked in the first place.   .  .