# What is the order of $\prod_{p\leq n} (1-1/p)^{-1} - \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, limits, prime-numbers

Let p is prime. In this question and answer ([Intuition for the prime number theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144940/intuition-for-the-prime-number-theorem/2145167)）, they approximate $  \prod_{p\leq n} (1-1/p)^{-1} \approx \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$. This is well known way to get the intuition of prime number theorem. However, I'm not convinced well.

How to know that the order of $$ \left( \prod_{p\leq n} (1-1/p)^{-1} - \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i \right)$$
is sufficiently small? In other words, $O(\log n)$.

Comment: Intuition means "the power or faculty of attaining to direct knowledge or cognition without evident rational thought and inference" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition), so there can't be a "method" for it by definition. $\Theta(\log n)$ or $o(\log n)$ aren't limits, but orders of magnitude. Suggestion: you might consider learning and applying definitions instead of "intuition".

Comment: I change the statement a little according to you.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "small". This is the same magnitude as the quantities being subtracted.

Comment: I mean, sufficiently small so that prime number thoerem would hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mertens' estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems) gives

$$ \prod_{p\leq n}(1-1/p)^{-1} = C\log n + O(1) $$

where $C=e^{\gamma} = 1.78\cdots$. Comparing this to the elementary estimate

$$ \sum_{i\leq n}\frac{1}{i} = \log n + O(1),$$

we see that in fact the difference

$$ \prod_{p\leq n} (1-1/p)^{-1}-\sum_{i\leq n}\frac{1}{i}  = (C-1)\log n+O(1),$$

so can give a precise asymptotic formula for the size of the difference. In particular, the difference is $O(\log n)$ (and this is the correct order of magnitude).